# Stubbing an API with Azure API Management

Tags: azure-api-management

I was wondering if someone was able to provide some information regarding the Azure Management Portal. My question is whether the Portal can cater for stubbing APIs?

I have added an API via the Portal as well as some operations however, the documentation isn't clear whether the real API has to be published to Azure.. I was thinking I can add example requests and responses without a real API behind it, i.e. a stub?

Comment: Are you talking about Azure API Management, Mobile Services or some other Azure service that supports custom APIs? What do you mean "I have added the API via Portal"?

Comment: Sorry I should be clearer. Yes. I mean I have added an API using the Azure API Management. I was thinking it would also house a stub?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a stub easily enough. See the default 'echo' endpoint that comes with each new API that you add to API Management. Copy that pattern and you can build a stub. The API Management documention is some of the better content for Azure so I'd recommend [reading it](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/api-management-get-started/).